# How to get the full content of an XML file as a String using XmlStreamReader?

Tags: java, string, file, xml-parsing, xmlstreamreader

I'm in a part of an application where I have an access to the `XmlStreamReader` which is representing the [XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML) file needed to be fully read into a `String`.

Is there a way to obtain the XML content without building another `XmlStreamReader` or using another stream on the [file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_file)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamReader;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactoryConfigurationError;
import javax.xml.transform.stax.StAXSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

private String getOuterXml(XMLStreamReader xmlr) throws TransformerConfigurationException,
    TransformerFactoryConfigurationError, TransformerException
{
    Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
    StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
    transformer.transform(new StAXSource(xmlr), new StreamResult(stringWriter));
    return stringWriter.toString();
}
```

Comment: Is there a better way to achieve this ? We are using the same method but a 20 MB file is getting exploded to 400MB using this conversion. Incase there is a better solution it will be helpful.